# Is Seki Tekko (the red glove with a blood drawing wristband) a part of Senketsu?

Tags: kill-la-kill

Ryuuko uses Seki Tekko, the glove with a wristband to pierce her skin and draw blood that Senketsu needs to transform and give her power. That glove was given to Ryuuko by Aikuro Mikisugi (the teach in pilot shades) in episode 2.

[image] [image]

It is colored red and is exactly what  Ryuuko needs to make use of Senketsu effectively. Was it just lying around in the teacher's closet for punishing  bad students and just happened to fit, or did Mikisugi make it specifically for Ryuuko? Where does this glove come from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This glove is originally a part of Senketsu. If you look carefully at the flashback scene in episode 3 where Mikisugi goes to the burned down Matoi house, in the basement where he finds Senketsu, you can see that the glove is in the left sleeve:

[image]